# Display a javascript variable content from mustache

Tags: javascript, internationalization, mustache

I have a page template made with mustache. The thing is that i have to translate the content of the Data into another language rather than english.

```
{{#variableToTranslate}}    
    <tr>
       <th>title</th>
       <td>{{variableToTranslate}}</td>
    </tr>
{{/variableToTranslate}}
```

to solve this, I have used a javascript function that return the translatedVariable.

My questions are:

- How can i display the translated variable?(how can i display the return of a javascript function in a mustache template).

> ```
> <script>
>     function translate(arg1,arg2){
>         return arg1+arg2;}
> </script>
> ```

```
{{#variableToTranslate}}    
    <tr>
        <th>title</th>
        <td>translate(arg1,arg2);</td>
    </tr>
{{/variableToTranslate}}
```

- Is there a better way to translate the content of a data set before displaying it.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Mustache templates actually supports lambdas:

From the docs: https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html

---

### Lambdas

When the value is a callable object, such as a function or lambda, the object will be invoked and passed the block of text. The text passed is the literal block, unrendered. {{tags}} will not have been expanded - the lambda should do that on its own. In this way you can implement filters or caching.

Template:

```
{{#wrapped}}
  {{name}} is awesome.
{{/wrapped}}
```

Hash:

```
{
  "name": "Willy",
  "wrapped": function() {
    return function(text, render) {
      return "<b>" + render(text) + "</b>"
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
<b>Willy is awesome.</b>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, however it didn't solve my problem, as i couldn't edit the hash adding a function as it is the server response.

Comment: @Lilia So you get the hash from the server?

Comment: @Lilia than that's just a json object, so you can add data to it before you pass it to the renderer.